# ASP.NET CustomRequestValidator not validating requests with non dangerous characters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

As we know, ASP.NET RequestValidator only works on http requests that contains dangerous characters that not encoded.

I would like to validate all the request fields even if they doesn't contains dangerous strings. Therefore, i tried to create a custom RequestValidator class but i can only override the method IsValidRequestString to do the validation and as i mentioned above, the method is not executing when the request does not contains dangerous characters.

in the RequestValidator document, i noticed that there is a method called InvokeIsValidRequestString but its not a virtual so i can not override it.

Is there an option to allow the overrided IsValidRequestString to be executed for every request? is there an option to override the InvokeIsValidRequestString  method somehow?

Comment: IMHO. Wouldn't this be better elsewhere - like in `Model`, input validation(s)? Unsure what "validation" you're looking for at some "global" level (that wouldn't already be caught). You'll likely affect some application/business level rules by trying to do "global".

Comment: I need it to be on the server side... for every request.